# How to get the interval for setInterval from user

Tags: javascript, setinterval

The `setInterval` inside the function won't actually call the `fibo` function but the one outside does. `getinfo` is the function call when the button is press. I'm trying to use the interval information we get to the user to use it for the set `interval(fibo,userEnterInterval)`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>problems</title>
    <b id="series">hi</b>

  </head>
  <body method="get">
    <form method="post">
    <label for="Range"> Range(N): </label>
      <input id="Range" type="text" placeholder="Range" name="Range">
      <label for="Interval"> Interval in seconds </label>
      <input id="Interval" type="text"enter code here placeholder="Interval" name="Interval">
      <input id="button" type="submit" onclick="getinfo()"  />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      var fis = [];
      function getinfo(){
        var interv = document.getElementById('Interval').value;
        var range = document.getElementById('Range').value;
        range =range*1000;
        setInterval(fibo,1000 );
      }
      setInterval(fibo,1000 );
      var printS = document.getElementById('series');
      function fibo(){
          if(fis.length == 0){
            printS.textContent = '0 ';
            fis.push(0);
          }else if( fis.length == 1){
            alert(fis.length);
            printS.textContent += '1 ';
            fis.push(1);
            alert(fis.length);
          }else{
            var next = fis[fis.length-1] + fis[fis.length-2];
            printS.textContent +=next.toString() + ' ';
            fis.push(next);
          }
        }





    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the actual question here? Also, "_the setInterval inside the function won't actually call the fibo function_", but it is, why wouldn't it?

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't because the button is submitting the form and refreshing the page?

Comment: Also check for console errors? Do you have any? And please clarify your issue, are you saying that the `setInterval` function isn't working at all? Or are you *trying* to say that it works but doesn't use the user defined duration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to prevent Default action of submitting the form.

```
<input id="button" type="submit" onclick="getinfo(event);"  />
function getinfo(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var interv = document.getElementById('Interval').value;
    var range = document.getElementById('Range').value;
    range =range*1000;
    setInterval(fibo,1000 );
  }
```

It will prevent the default action of submitting the page. Which of course means that interval will execute.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `interv` when setting the frequency of the interval:

```
setInterval(fibo,1000 * interv);
```

But this won't stop the old timer from running. You should assign it to a variable and stop it before restarting it with the new interval.

```
  function getinfo(){
    var interv = document.getElementById('Interval').value;
    var range = document.getElementById('Range').value;
    range =range*1000;
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = setInterval(fibo,1000 * interv);
  }
  var timer = setInterval(fibo,1000 );
```

You should also change the button to `type="submit"` so that it doesn't submit the form, which will reload the page and stop the script.

Comment: Why would using `interv` suddenly make `setInterval` start working? There is nothing wrong with the current `setInterval` call. The user claims that the function doesn't work at all, there is no mention that it is working but not using the correct duration...

Comment: I thought he might be confused because the function continued to run at the old interval, when he thought he changed the frequency.

Comment: E.g. he changes it from 1 second to 5 seconds, but it keeps updating every second, so he thinks the new interval isn't running.

Comment: It's possible you are right... the question is quite poorly described to be fair. But the first sentence suggests to me that the function isn't working at all

Comment: I'm answering the part that says **im trying to use the interval information we get to the user to use it for the set interval(fibo,userEnterInterval)**

Comment: Yeah, but that part isn't the actual problem/question, that's just back story. I am sure your info will be useful as the OP clearly hasn't worked that part out yet, but I don't think it's the solution to the question

Comment: I also added the part about the submit button, which is probably the real problem.

Comment: actually, i done that. my queston was that if you try running it. the etInterval(fibo,1000 * interv); inside getinfo does not work . still does not work. only the one outside runs but obviously it runs instantly. the button is already submit by the way.